# Laravel Query returning less rows than MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel

Very confused right now

Have the following query:

```
    $students = DB::select('SELECT students.id,students.student_name,students.student_middle_names, students.student_surname,
                                        COALESCE(SUM(student_medical_aids.monthly_contribution),0) AS medical_aid,COALESCE(SUM(student_bursaries.subsidy_allowance),0) AS subsidy,COALESCE(SUM(student_bursaries.tuition_value),0) AS tuition
                                    FROM students
                                        LEFT JOIN student_bursaries ON students.id=student_bursaries.student_id
                                        LEFT JOIN student_medical_aids ON students.id=student_medical_aids.student_id
                                    WHERE 
                                        students.status IN (:status) AND
                                        (YEAR(registration_date)<=:report_year OR registration_date IS NULL) 
                                    GROUP BY students.id
                                    ORDER BY student_name, student_middle_names, student_surname',

        [
            'status' => '1,4,6,7',
            'report_year' => date('Y', strtotime($this->report_to_date))
        ]);

    log::debug(print_r($students,true));
```

In MySQL (connected directly to the homestead VM [laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 9.4.0)]), it returns 185 rows.
In Laravel (either on the output, or the log file since I'm dumping it above) - only returns 182 rows.

Its not like I'm running the query on a different version of MySQL?
I found a row its excluding and couldnt find anything untoward (no funny characters, sub data of the join exists - not that it matters because its a LEFT join - not an INNER join).

I'm stumped!

Why would Laravel (Laravel Framework 7.7.1) leave out some rows? Am I mis-using DB::select?

//Update
Converting from a 'select' to a 'table' query did the job and I am now getting 185 rows as per the raw mysql query. If someone could please tell me why and what I was doing wrong, that would be great!

Working Query:

```
    $students = DB::table('students')
                    ->select('students.id','students.student_name','students.student_middle_names','students.student_surname',
                        DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(student_medical_aids.monthly_contribution),0) AS medical_aid'),
                        DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(student_bursaries.subsidy_allowance),0) AS subsidy'),
                        DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(student_bursaries.tuition_value),0) AS tuition'))
                    ->leftJoin('student_bursaries','students.id','=','student_bursaries.student_id')
                    ->leftJoin('student_medical_aids','students.id','=','student_medical_aids.student_id')
                    ->whereIn('students.status',[1,4,6,7])
                    ->where(function($query) {
                        $query->whereYear('registration_date','<=',date('Y', strtotime($this->report_to_date)))
                            ->orWhereNull('registration_date');
                    })
                    ->groupBy('students.id')
                    ->orderBy('student_name')
                    ->orderBy('student_middle_names')
                    ->orderBy('student_surname')->get();
```